# How do I get the instance name of a user control?

Tags: user-controls

I have a user control in .NET 2010. I dragged it on to a page twice. Obviously, both have the same functions. But, depending on which instance was clicked, I want to run the function diffenetly. How can I tell which user control was clicked?

....
Let me add to this. It is a user control with a datalist in it. The data list contains numerous clickable images. When the image is clicked, I am trying to grab the name of the instance to use in the code of the user control itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated To Match Comment**

The easiest way would be to use the `sender` parameter in your event handler. In your case, you should be able to cast to `Control` and then use the `Parent` property to get to the actual UserControl:

```
public void UserControlClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var senderAsControl = sender as Control;
    var name = senderAsControl.Parent.Name;
}
```

Comment: Sender is coming through as just System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView (which is the Listview in the user control) for both instances.

Comment: @2AllBeefPatty - Maybe I'm mis-understanding your page layout then. Can you add some example markup to your post?

Comment: Too complicated. Look, picture I have a simple User control with 1 button on it.  I drag it onto my aspx page and it created control1 and control2. Clicking the button sets string s = name of control instance (control1 or control2). That's all I really want to do.